# Set object in another class?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ipad

I have one class, "DogViewController", where I declare a property and synthesize it:

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) NSInteger myInt;

@synthesize myInt;
```

I have another class, `"CatViewController"`, in which I want to set the myInt variable, so this is what I did:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) DogViewController *myDogViewController;

@synthesize myDogViewController;

myDogViewController.myInt = 5;
```

I then want to access myInt from the DogViewController class, which I do by:

```
someVar = self.myInt;
```

someVar should be == 5 after that command.

Is there a reason why that would not work?

Comment: Have you instantiated `myDogViewController` by the time you do `myDogViewController.myInt = 5;`?

Comment: Doesn't the @property command instantiate it?

Comment: The @property directive just instructs the Objective-C pre-compiler to prepare to create getters and setters in your implementation file. The @synthesize keywords then causes the pre-compiler to inject the actual getter/setter code (unless you override those methods manually). If your properties need to be initialized you need to do that separately (for example, in a constructor).

Answer (score 1):

You must instantiate DogViewController first. So in CatViewController:

```
DogViewController *dogViewController = [[DogViewController alloc] initWithNibName@"DogViewController" bundle:nil];
dogViewController.myInt = 5;
// If you are using a navigation controller push DogViewController like this: 
[self.navigationController pushViewController:dogViewController animated:YES];
[dogViewController release];
```

If you are not using a navigation controller just display that view in whatever way you want

Comment: Could you edit your answer to reflect the fact the OP may not be using a view controller?

Comment: Sure - but wasn't the question talking about VC's though?

Comment: based on the OP's other questions on SO today, these are not VC's. Ofc, he also never stated in this question that they are - always safe to take the lowest common denominator.

Answer (score 0):

Try with not using `retain` with basic data type use `assign` instead .

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) NSInteger myInt;
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you will not get value 5. Because it will be reset.

You can do it like below way.

inside your "CatViewController", create one method like "setParent"

take in variable in .h file:

id parent;

function in .m file:

```
-(void)setParent:(id)pidParent{
parent = pidParent;
}
```

import "DogViewController.h" in CatViewController.m file.

When you push to the  DogViewController then also called it's setParent method.

Like
[objDogViewController setParent:self];

then you can set value by using "parent" variable.

Cheers.

Comment: This is not the cause of his problem. The DogViewController in his example is never getting initialized, which is why he cannot access any of its properties.